# What is the exact method to set the url in Kartik Sidenav in Yii2

Tags: url, yii2

In my computer I've set the link as following in kartik sidenav

```
'url' => 'http://localhost:8080/advanced/frontend/web/index.php?r=batchno/productbatch/create',
                                    'label' => 'New Batch',
                                    'icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign',
                                    'visible'=>Yii::$app->user->can('c_billing-person'),
```

It Works Fine. But in other computer with same database setup it's not working as I need to give the URL as below

```
http://localhost/advanced/frontend/web/index.php?r=batchno/productbatch/create
```

So the difference is in the port.
My question is that how can I set the URL dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A correct method for setting the url with yii2 (included kartik sidenav) is base on Url Helper

```
use yii\helpers\Url;


$menuItems[] =  ['label' => 'my_label',  'url'=>Url::to(['/your-controller/your-action'])];
```

in you case

```
'url'=>Url::to(['/batchno/productbatch/create'])
```

The Url Helper Url::to function provide the corretc routing for controller action in every environment ..